# Recorrer varios select

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, select

Buenos días comunidad!

Tengo una duda. Necesito recorrer varios select, y obtener la option seleccionada en cada uno. Cada select tiene un id diferente que no puedo saberlo ya que es el id de una tabla de donde obtengo los datos, también la cantidad, puede haber un select como también pueden haber 200.

HTML

```
                    <table id="tablaDeLicencia" class="table table-condensed table-striped">
                   <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Funcionario</th>
                            <th>Documento</th>
                            <th>Area</th>
                            <th>Periodo</th>
                            <th>Dias</th>
                            <th>Solicitado</th>
                            <th>Aprobacion</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody> 
                        {% for solicitud in solicitudes %}                  
                            <tr class="hidde-odd">
                                <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">{{ solicitud.nombre_solicitud }}</td>
                                <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">{{ solicitud.documento_solicitud }}</td>
                                <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">{{ solicitud.area_solicitud }}</td>
                                <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">{{ solicitud.periodo_solicitud }}</td>
                                <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">{{ solicitud.cantidad_solicitud }}</td>
                                <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">{{ solicitud.fecha_solicitud }}</td>
                                <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">
                                    <select name="estadoSolicitud" id="{{ solicitud.id_solicitud }}">
                                      <option value="0" selected="true">En Espera</option>
                                      <option value="1">Aprobar</option>
                                      <option value="2">No Aprobar</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

JS

```
function actualizarSolicitudes(){
   document.querySelectorAll('#tablaDeLicencia input[type=select]').forEach(function(checkElement) {
       if(checkElement.checked == true){
            count++;
        }
    });
```

}

desde ya, muchas gracias.

Saludos

Comment: Qué has intentado? Pon el código que tienes

Comment: Puse los códigos

Comment: Esto es lenguaje php?

Comment: La obtención de los Selected lo quiero hacer desde JS, de php traigo los datos para imprimir en el html

Comment: Cuando creas los `select` puedes añadir el atributo `name` y dejarles el mismo nombre a todos, cuando quieras acceder a ellos los haces `const selects= document.getElementsByName("select_name");` esto te va a crear un arreglo de objetos, y los vas a poder manipular como un arreglo. [Fuente](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya casi lo tenias, con el código de muestra que hay más abajo puedes ver cual es la opción seleccionada de cada uno de los select.

Básicamente los cambios han sido:

- Usar como selector a buscar esto:

```
#tablaDeLicencia select
```

- Y una vez encontrados, aprovechando el forEach que ya tenias, tan solo necesitas usar [selectedIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) para descubrir cual está seleccionado (en caso de que no haya ningun **option** aparecerá -1).

```
el.selectedIndex
```

### Ejemplo completo

```js
function actualizarSolicitudes() {
  document.querySelectorAll('#tablaDeLicencia select').forEach(function(el) {
    console.log(el.selectedIndex)
  });
}
actualizarSolicitudes()
```

```html
<table id="tablaDeLicencia" class="table table-condensed table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Funcionario</th>
      <th>Documento</th>
      <th>Area</th>
      <th>Periodo</th>
      <th>Dias</th>
      <th>Solicitado</th>
      <th>Aprobacion</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="hidde-odd">
      <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">nombre</td>
      <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">documento</td>
      <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">area</td>
      <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">periodo</td>
      <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">cantidad</td>
      <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">fecha</td>
      <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">
        <select name="estadoSolicitud" id="id_solicitud1">
          <option value="0" selected="true">En Espera</option>
          <option value="1">Aprobar</option>
          <option value="2">No Aprobar</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidde-odd">
      <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">nombre1</td>
      <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">documento1</td>
      <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">area1</td>
      <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">periodo1</td>
      <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">cantidad1</td>
      <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">fecha1</td>
      <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">
        <select name="estadoSolicitud" id="id_solicitud2">
          <option value="0">En Espera</option>
          <option value="1" selected>Aprobar</option>
          <option value="2">No Aprobar</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidde-odd">
      <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">nombre2</td>
      <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">documento2</td>
      <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">area2</td>
      <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">periodo2</td>
      <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">cantidad2</td>
      <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">fecha2</td>
      <td class="acot-xgr-gr1">
        <select name="estadoSolicitud" id="id_solicitud3">
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias masterguru! el id lo obtengo con el.id

Comment: Perdón, me confundí de id, pensé que el de la tabla se repetia, fallo mio, olvida lo que he dicho.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que se me ocurre que puedes hacer es traerte todos los elementos OPTION que tienen un atributo selected = true.

Puedes iterar por cada opción y obtener su select padre por si quieres saber a que select pertenece.

```javascript
var selected_options = document.querySelectorAll('option[selected="true"]')

var selects = []

selected_options.forEach(option => {
    selects.push(option.parentNode)
})
```

Comment: Esto es incorrecto: `Como tal el elemento que devuelve querySelectorAll no tiene método forEach.`.  Revisa su [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#accediendo_a_las_coincidencias) y lo verás.